# How to sum each unique last value from table

Tags: mysql, sum

I want to SUM the total amount of KG of each unique last value in a table.

The table i currently have looks like this

```
|----|-----------|----------|----------|----------|---------------|
| id | productId | amountKg | amountSt | location | datetimeStamp |
|----|-----------|----------|----------|----------|---------------|
| 12 | 19        | 201      | 0        | loc1     | 2019-12-21    |
| 13 | 19        | 35       | 0        | loc2     | 2019-12-22    |  <---
| 14 | 19        | 400      | 0        | loc1     | 2019-12-23    |  <---
|----|-----------|----------|----------|----------|---------------|
```

And I have this SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(amountKg) FROM (SELECT amountKg FROM storage GROUP BY location ORDER BY id ASC) t;
```

Whe  I run this query I get the result 236
The result I want is 435, the sum of the 14 and 13 (The arrows in the table)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure about the semantics of selecting a non-aggregated value in an aggregation query, but if you `ORDER BY id ASC` in the inner query, I'd expect it to return the value for the _lowest_ id (just take the first value, if they are ordered ascending, that is the lowest one). Have you tried ordering `DESC`?

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Comment: I have tried order by DESC but I still get 236 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find first the ID's that have the latest row for each location and then sum those together:

```
select sum(s.amountKg)
from storage s
  join ( 
    select location, max(id) as id
    from storage
    group by location
  ) as latest on latest.id=s.id
```

See [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com)